# some delay processing message in MessageInterceptor

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sms

Sorry, my english is not quite well.

I'm new in programming world and tried to create an application using messageinterceptor on windows mobile 6.5.3.
but when i send text message to my phone, there was delay about 30 seconds or  more before the message is processed, either text message which contain keywords or not.

I read several sources before deciding to try to make my own application, but these source are using Windows Form (GUI), instead of using Windows Form, i make it run in console mode.

here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.MessageInterception;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile;
using System.IO;

namespace PenerimaPesan
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string applicationID;
            applicationID = "tracker";

            MessageInterceptor pesanmasuk = null;
            pesanmasuk = new MessageInterceptor();
            pesanmasuk.EnableApplicationLauncher(applicationID);


            if (MessageInterceptor.IsApplicationLauncherEnabled(applicationID))
            {
                string keyword;
                StreamReader key = new StreamReader(@"\Windows\conf.txt");
                string data = key.ReadToEnd();
                string[] isi = data.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
                keyword = isi[1];
                keyword = keyword.Replace(" ", "");

                pesanmasuk = new MessageInterceptor(InterceptionAction.NotifyAndDelete, false);
                pesanmasuk.MessageCondition = new MessageCondition(MessageProperty.Body, MessagePropertyComparisonType.StartsWith, ""+keyword);
                pesanmasuk.MessageReceived += new MessageInterceptorEventHandler(pesanmasuk_MessageReceived);
            }
        }

        static void pesanmasuk_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageInterceptorEventArgs e)
        {
            SmsMessage pesan = e.Message as SmsMessage;

            if (pesan != null)
            {
                string perintah;
                string[] command = pesan.Body.Split(new char[] { '.' });
                perintah = command[1];

                if (perintah == "helo")

                /*do some Stuff*/
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a UI app just to see if you see the same delay?  It may have something to do with processing windows messages if the interceptor uses them (I don't know if it does).

Comment: I think you are blowing away your initial instance. See my detailed answer below.

Comment: @ctacke : i've try GUI / Form version, (i got from internet) it's work fine. so, it maybe there is something wrong with my code

Comment: @jp2code : i have tried your code with some fix (some code didn't work in windows mobile sdk) now my application works fine. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used `MessageInterceptor`, so I decided I'd try to implement this code in my application. To test it, I renamed **Main** to **Main2**, then cleaned it up to match "my style".

Anyway, I ran into errors when I tried wrapping the `MessageInterceptor` in a `using` block - not because `MessageInterceptor` does not implement `IDispose`, but because you have declared a new instance of it.

Take a look at this snippet of your code:

```
MessageInterceptor pesanmasuk = new MessageInterceptor();
pesanmasuk.EnableApplicationLauncher(applicationID);
if (MessageInterceptor.IsApplicationLauncherEnabled(applicationID)) {
  string keyword;
  StreamReader key = new StreamReader(@"\Windows\conf.txt");
  string data = key.ReadToEnd();
  string[] isi = data.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
  keyword = isi[1];
  keyword = keyword.Replace(" ", "");
  pesanmasuk = new MessageInterceptor(InterceptionAction.NotifyAndDelete, false);
```

OK, right there. **Stop.** You created a new instance of your `pesanmasuk` variable, set Properties, did some checking, worked with data from a text file, then...

Created a new instance of your `pesanmasuk` variable.

**All of your previous settings are now whipped out.**

I'm guessing your first instance is running and perhaps the second instance has to wait for the first instance to time out before it can be created.

At this point, I'm interested to learn just how to use this `MessageInterceptor` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb932385.aspx), looked into the example there, and came up with this [untested] version:

```
static void Main2(string[] args) {
  const string stackOverflowUrl = @"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520488/some-delay-processing-message-in-messageinterceptor";
  string empty = String.Empty;
  StreamReader key = new StreamReader(@"\Windows\conf.txt");
  string data = key.ReadToEnd();
  string[] lines = data.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
  string keyword = lines[1].Replace(" ", empty);
  string applicationID = "trackingApplication";
  using (MessageInterceptor smsInterceptor = new MessageInterceptor(applicationID, false)) {
    smsInterceptor.InterceptionAction = InterceptionAction.NotifyAndDelete;
    smsInterceptor.MessageCondition = new MessageCondition(MessageProperty.Body, MessagePropertyComparisonType.StartsWith, empty + keyword);
    smsInterceptor.MessageReceived += new MessageInterceptorEventHandler(Intercept_MessageReceived);
    smsInterceptor.EnableApplicationLauncher(applicationID);
    if (MessageInterceptor.IsApplicationLauncherEnabled(applicationID)) {
      // Here, you'd need to launch your Form1 or enable some timer,
      // otherwise the code will return immediately and the MessageInterceptor
      // instance will be disposed of.
    }
    smsInterceptor.MessageReceived -= MessageInterceptorEventHandler;
  }
}

static void Intercept_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageInterceptorEventArgs e) {
  SmsMessage newMessage = e.Message as SmsMessage;
  if (newMessage != null) {
    Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", newMessage.From.Address);
    Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", newMessage.Body);
    string[] command = newMessage.Body.Split(new char[] { '.' });
    string line = command[1];
    if (line == "helo") {
      /*do some Stuff*/
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps, but keep in mind that I've never actually used this control and my code has not been tested.